# How build a Tree (AST) of several generic constructors in F#?

Tags: generics, f#, interpreter, algebraic-data-types

I'm building a little array language, and struggle to see how encode the arrays with generics:

```
type Shape<'T> =
    | Col of array<'T>
    | Rel of array<Shape<'T>>

let makeArray (value:array<'T>) =  Col value

type ExprC = 
    | BoolC of bool array
    | StrC of string array
    | IntC of int array

# Here is ExprC -> Shape<bool>
let eval (ast : ExprC) = 
    match ast with
    | BoolC(v) -> makeArray v
    | StrC(v) -> makeArray v
    | IntC(v) -> makeArray v
```

I wanna a way to encode any .NET object as array yet be able to interpret it with the lang.

Comment: I am not quite clear on the question.Could you provide a little more information or maybe an example of how you plan to use this code.

Comment: I wanna to avoid to box/unbox all the values, so wonder if exist a way to make `eval` to become  `ExprC -> Shape<'T>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit stuck here, you need a language with higher kinded types.